# Forming a Hessian Matrix of particular functions

Tags: calculus, functions, quadratics, quadratic-forms, hessian-matrix

Given the following functions,

- $f(x, y, z) = −x^3 + 3xz + 2y − y^2 − 3z^2$
- $f(x, y) = 3x^4 + 3x^2y − y^3$

I've been told that you can form the following respective Hessian matrices, such that you can evaluate the LPM's / PM's to classify the stationary points of both functions:

- \begin{pmatrix}
  -6x & 0 & 3\\ 
  0 & -2 & 0\\ 
  3 & 0 & -6
  \end{pmatrix}
- \begin{pmatrix}
  36x^2 +6y& 6x \\ 
  6x & -6y \\ 
  \end{pmatrix}

Could someone explain how these matrices were worked out? I only know how to form a Hessian from the Quadratic form: $ax^2 + by^2 + cz^2 + 2fxy + 2gxz + 2hyz$, and I can't seem to figure out how to do so otherwise. Help is much appreciated.

Comment: The functions you've given are not quadratic forms: they involve terms with total degree $\neq 2$! I think you're confusing the *Gram matrix* of a quadratic form and the [Hessian matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessian_matrix#Definitions_and_properties) of a multivariable function.

Comment: @André3000 Hi thanks for the comment. My mistake, I have made an edit to correct this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first one: first work out the Jacobian matrix - the matrix of partial derivatives. For each entry, differentiate $f$ with respect to each variable, treating the other two variables as constants.
$$Jf(x,y,z)=\begin{pmatrix}f_x & f_y & f_z\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}-3x^2+3z&2-2y&3x-6z\end{pmatrix}$$
Then work out the Hessian matrix - the matrix of second partial derivatives. For example,
$$f_{xx}=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(-3x^2+3z)=-6x$$
and
$$f_{xy}=\frac{\partial}{\partial y}(-3x^2+3z)=0.$$
Doing this for all entries produces the Hessian matrix
$$Hf(x,y,z)=\begin{pmatrix}f_{xx}&f_{xy}&f_{xz}\\f_{yx}&f_{yy}&f_{yz}\\f_{zx}&f_{zy}&f_{zz}\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}-6x&0&3\\0&-2&0\\3&0&-6\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Perfect. Of course, it all makes sense now. I got too used to extracting the Hessian purely by looking at the coefficients of the standard Quadratic form and forgot the actual definition. Thank you.